# ANOVA comparison of non-significant mixed models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have two nested mixed models: the difference in these models is the presence of one predictor variable (`type`). I used `lmerTest` to obtain p-values for the model, and none except the intercept were significant. Can I still compare these models using `anova` to say the predictor variable `type` is (or is not) having an effect on the model?

```
m1 <- lmer(f2 ~ sex + type + (1|speaker))
m2 <- lmer(f2 ~ sex + (1|speaker))
anova(m1, m2)
```

Comment: Have you already run this code? Do you get a significant or a non-significant difference?

Comment: I have run this code (my actual code has a few more predictor variables, though) and get a p-value of 0.9885, which I take to mean that these models are not significantly different and therefore it is unlikely that the predictor variable `type` has a significant effect

Comment: That's right, this means that the difference is not statistically significant (whether it is "likely" that type has an effect or not, we cannot really say; it depends on how "likely" you thought it was before running your experiment and on many other things). So in your case the conclusions of `lmerTest` and of `anova` agree. I am not sure what exactly is then your question.

Comment: My question is: Can I compare these mixed models despite the fact that the individual models do not show any significant effects?

Comment: Sure. This question suggests that perhaps you do not quite understand what is going on here. Comparing `m1` and `m2` is equivalent to testing whether `type` is a significant predictor in `m1`. So running `anova(m1, m2)` and running `lmerTest` on `m1` are just two different ways to test if `type` is significant. You can use either of these two ways, or both, if you like. You are testing the same thing two times. Does it make sense?

Comment: Oh, okay. Yes, it does make sense! Thank you! Maybe I'm having a problem with interpretation in general - because all these other predictors that I have included in the model should have an effect, and I'm not sure why they don't.